# Codeigniter combining information

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, model

first of, just wanted to let you know that I am a newbie at CI. but I am having trouble with this piece of code where is breaking and I can't seem to be able to find the answer anywhere.

for some reason the code is breaking at the first if statement.. if possible could you help me out understand what is really happening there?

Thank you all for your help!

```
function main
{
$this->load->model(getData) psudo code for this area...
}
```

---model---
    function getData....
    {
    Sql = this->db->query(sql code that returns all the information required.)
    $result = $sql->result_array();

```
$types = array ( 'EVENT|TIME' => array( 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'Regular' ),
        'PROPOSITION|REGULAR' => array( 'id' => 2, 'name' =>'Propositions'),
        'EVENT|TIME' => array( 'id' => 3, 'name' => 'Now' ),
        'PROPOSITION|FUTURES' => array( 'id' => 4, 'name' => 'Future' ));
$var = array();
foreach ($result as $event) {
    $cat = $event['type'] . '|' . $event['sub_type'];
        $typeId = $types[$cat]['id'];

    if(!is_array($var[$event['event_id']]['var'][$event['type_id']]))                               
               { 
       if(!is_array($var[$event['event_id']]))
                 {
        $var[$event['event_id']] = array( 'event_name' =>            
                    $event['event_name'],'event_abbreviation' => 
                    $event['event_abbreviation']);                                      
                 }

        $var[$event['event_id']]['var'][$event['type_id']] =  array(  
          'type_name' => $event['abbreviation'],'type_abbreviation' => $event['name']                                                                                                                                               
        );
    }

    $event[$event['event_id']]['var'][$event['type_id']]['types'][$typeId] = 
      $types[$cat]['name'];

}

return $myResults;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
if(!is_array($var[$event['event_id']]['var']$event['type_id']]))
```

You are missing a `[` somewhere. I'm guessing before `$event['type_id']`.
So replace with:

```
if(!is_array($var[$event['event_id']]['var'][$event['type_id']]))
```

Comment: you are right! I was missing '[' however now, I am getting an error .. Message 'Undefined offset:1' that goes from 1 -8 :/

Comment: @user3307667 On the same line? It's because $var[1] to $var[8] don't exist yet and you're checking for arrays insides those. You can use !isset($var[...]) to check if they don't exist.